# A better way to deploy a Debian-python hybrid application

Tags: python, docker, deployment, debian, dpkg

I wrote a small application for Debian linux that calls python2.7 to perform almost all of its functions.
The python functions include for example remote database access, so the app will depend on python modules that are not in every linux distribution by default.

The app is packaged in a dpkg file in order to be used on many other machines (with same linux distribution), using `dpkg -i MyApp01`.

But the python dependencies have to be installed separately in order for the app to work: for example `pip install mysql-connector-python-rf`

Now I want to use Docker to ship my dependencies with the app and make it work on other machines without having to install them as above.
Can Docker be used to do this?and how?

If no, Is there a better approach to natively bundle the python dependencies in the dpkg file (assuming target machines have similar environment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A container is an isolated environment, so you have to ship all what will be needed for your program to run.

Your Dockerfile will be based on Debian, so begin with

`FROM debian`

and will have some

`RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y mysoft mydependency1 mydependency2`

and also

`RUN pip install xxx`

and end with something like

`CMD ["python","myapp.py"]`

As your Python program does certainly things like

`import module1, module2`

Those Python modules will need to be installed in your Dockerfile in a RUN directive